# How to show Toast in class which extends Activity

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, android-activity, android-toast

I have a Java Class in my Android project, where I wanted to separate facebook authorization from email authorization. Because of this line

```
 LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));
```

I was obliged to extend my FBLogin class from Activity. Did I do it right or I should have done in other way?

But my main Question is - how to show a Toast message in this FBLogin class? this line shows me errors

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: if `FBLogin ` class extends Activity then use `FBLogin.this` instead of `getActivity()`

Comment: just replace getActivity() with yourclas.this

Comment: Can you post some more code of the place you are calling Toast.makeText(...) ?  Toast works in UI thread are you sure you are not calling it from another thread? The stacktrace of the errors also could be handy if you post it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
Toast.makeText(fblogin.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

For normal Activity:

```
Toast.makeText(FBLogin.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

extends Fragment:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
Toast.makeText(YourClassName.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Like if your Class Name is MainActivity then you have to do this

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity .this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

or you can pass Context of your Application.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```